# Connect my Azure Windows Server to a godaddy domain

Tags: azure, dns, active-directory, cloudflare

I wish to connect an active directory controller which is hosted on an Azuer VPS to a domain I have purchased (which uses CloudFlare), how can I go about doing so?

I am aware of the security risks imposed by exposing an AD instance to the public.

I have poked around to try and find details about what ports should be exposed and records that should be created but couldn't find any.

Edit: I found a page containing a list of the required records and managed to configure it correctly - I will now add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS is now properly configured for the AD instance to be exposed to the web.

I followed the records available [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servergeeks/2014/07/12/dns-records-that-are-required-for-proper-functionality-of-active-directory/) and now it's for all to see!